# Display two rows of data in one row using vuetify v-data-table

Tags: c#, vue.js, vuetify.js

This is how I coded my display on the data table

```
<template v-slot:item.column2="{ item }">
     <div>
       <td v-for="value in item.column2">
          {{ value }}
       </td>
    </div>
</template>
```

Is there a way for me to display two rows of data into one row only with the items stacked on top of each other using v-data-table? currently it displays the data side by side
`Company 1 Company ABC`

```
   id    | columnt 2 | column 3
   1       Company 1     Test1
           Company ABC   Test2
----------------------------------
   2         text        text
             text        text
```

then  my data would be coming in looking like this

```
this.pendingApprovals = [
        {
          id: 1,
          column2:
          {
            oldValue: 'Company 1',
            newValue: 'Company ABC',
          },
          column2: [
            {
              oldValue: 'Test1',
              newValue: 'Test2',
            },
          ],         
        },
      ];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You misorder the `div` and `td`. Here is the right order code.

```
<template v-slot:item.column2="{ item }">
     <td>
       <div v-for="value in item.column2">
          {{ value }}
       </div>
    </td>
</template>
```